# overriden method of ItemizedOverlay class get get called multiple times

Tags: android, google-maps, itemizedoverlay

I am facing some issues as the createItem(int i) method of ItemizedOverlay class get called multiple times for each overlayItem that i added in itemizedOverlay object.

You will get better idea by watching my logcat output.

```
    01-01 20:51:33.486: I/System.out(690): addOverlay is called
01-01 20:51:33.497: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 0
01-01 20:51:33.506: I/System.out(690): addOverlay is called
01-01 20:51:33.517: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 0
01-01 20:51:33.526: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 1
01-01 20:51:33.536: I/System.out(690): addOverlay is called
01-01 20:51:33.536: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 0
01-01 20:51:33.546: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 1
01-01 20:51:33.556: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 2
01-01 20:51:33.576: I/System.out(690): addOverlay is called
01-01 20:51:33.576: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 0
01-01 20:51:33.596: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 1
01-01 20:51:33.606: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 2
01-01 20:51:33.616: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 3
01-01 20:51:33.637: I/System.out(690): addOverlay is called
01-01 20:51:33.637: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 0
01-01 20:51:33.657: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 1
01-01 20:51:33.676: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 2
01-01 20:51:33.696: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 3
01-01 20:51:33.708: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 4
01-01 20:51:33.726: I/System.out(690): addOverlay is called
01-01 20:51:33.726: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 0
01-01 20:51:33.736: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 1
01-01 20:51:33.757: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 2
01-01 20:51:33.776: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 3
01-01 20:51:33.796: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 4
01-01 20:51:33.816: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 5
01-01 20:51:33.836: I/System.out(690): addOverlay is called
01-01 20:51:33.836: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 0
01-01 20:51:33.846: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 1
01-01 20:51:33.866: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 2
01-01 20:51:33.886: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 3
01-01 20:51:33.897: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 4
01-01 20:51:33.906: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 5
01-01 20:51:33.916: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 6
01-01 20:51:33.936: I/System.out(690): addOverlay is called
01-01 20:51:33.936: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 0
01-01 20:51:33.958: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 1
01-01 20:51:33.976: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 2
01-01 20:51:33.996: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 3
01-01 20:51:34.016: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 4
01-01 20:51:34.036: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 5
01-01 20:51:34.056: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 6
01-01 20:51:34.056: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 7
01-01 20:51:34.087: I/System.out(690): addOverlay is called
01-01 20:51:34.087: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 0
01-01 20:51:34.096: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 1
01-01 20:51:34.106: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 2
01-01 20:51:34.127: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 3
01-01 20:51:34.146: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 4
01-01 20:51:34.166: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 5
01-01 20:51:34.176: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 6
01-01 20:51:34.196: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 7
01-01 20:51:34.206: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 8
01-01 20:51:34.216: I/System.out(690): addOverlay is called
01-01 20:51:34.216: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 0
01-01 20:51:34.236: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 1
01-01 20:51:34.247: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 2
01-01 20:51:34.256: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 3
01-01 20:51:34.266: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 4
01-01 20:51:34.286: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 5
01-01 20:51:34.306: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 6
01-01 20:51:34.318: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 7
01-01 20:51:34.336: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 8
01-01 20:51:34.346: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 9
01-01 20:51:34.366: I/System.out(690): addOverlay is called
01-01 20:51:34.366: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 0
01-01 20:51:34.376: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 1
01-01 20:51:34.396: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 2
01-01 20:51:34.406: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 3
01-01 20:51:34.428: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 4
01-01 20:51:34.436: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 5
01-01 20:51:34.446: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 6
01-01 20:51:34.456: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 7
01-01 20:51:34.476: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 8
01-01 20:51:34.496: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 9
01-01 20:51:34.506: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 10
01-01 20:51:34.526: I/System.out(690): addOverlay is called
01-01 20:51:34.526: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 0
01-01 20:51:34.536: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 1
01-01 20:51:34.556: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 2
01-01 20:51:34.566: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 3
01-01 20:51:34.586: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 4
01-01 20:51:34.606: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 5
01-01 20:51:34.616: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 6
01-01 20:51:34.616: I/dalvikvm(690): Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024
01-01 20:51:34.706: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 7
01-01 20:51:34.716: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 8
01-01 20:51:34.736: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 9
01-01 20:51:34.756: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 10
01-01 20:51:34.766: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 11
01-01 20:51:34.776: I/System.out(690): addOverlay is called
01-01 20:51:34.786: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 0
01-01 20:51:34.796: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 1
01-01 20:51:34.816: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 2
01-01 20:51:34.828: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 3
01-01 20:51:34.846: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 4
01-01 20:51:34.856: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 5
01-01 20:51:34.876: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 6
01-01 20:51:34.886: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 7
01-01 20:51:34.906: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 8
01-01 20:51:34.919: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 9
01-01 20:51:34.926: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 10
01-01 20:51:34.936: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 11
01-01 20:51:34.956: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 12
01-01 20:51:34.976: I/System.out(690): addOverlay is called
01-01 20:51:34.976: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 0
01-01 20:51:34.987: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 1
01-01 20:51:35.006: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 2
01-01 20:51:35.026: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 3
01-01 20:51:35.046: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 4
01-01 20:51:35.066: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 5
01-01 20:51:35.076: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 6
01-01 20:51:35.097: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 7
01-01 20:51:35.108: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 8
01-01 20:51:35.126: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 9
01-01 20:51:35.146: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 10
01-01 20:51:35.168: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 11
01-01 20:51:35.186: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 12
01-01 20:51:35.196: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 13
01-01 20:51:35.216: I/System.out(690): addOverlay is called
01-01 20:51:35.216: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 0
01-01 20:51:35.228: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 1
01-01 20:51:35.250: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 2
01-01 20:51:35.256: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 3
01-01 20:51:35.267: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 4
01-01 20:51:35.286: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 5
01-01 20:51:35.296: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 6
01-01 20:51:35.306: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 7
01-01 20:51:35.326: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 8
01-01 20:51:35.336: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 9
01-01 20:51:35.356: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 10
01-01 20:51:35.366: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 11
01-01 20:51:35.376: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 12
01-01 20:51:35.396: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 13
01-01 20:51:35.406: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 14
01-01 20:51:35.426: I/System.out(690): addOverlay is called
01-01 20:51:35.426: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 0
01-01 20:51:35.438: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 1
01-01 20:51:35.456: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 2
01-01 20:51:35.476: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 3
01-01 20:51:35.486: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 4
01-01 20:51:35.506: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 5
01-01 20:51:35.516: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 6
01-01 20:51:35.526: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 7
01-01 20:51:35.536: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 8
01-01 20:51:35.557: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 9
01-01 20:51:35.566: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 10
01-01 20:51:35.576: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 11
01-01 20:51:35.596: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 12
01-01 20:51:35.608: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 13
01-01 20:51:35.616: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 14
01-01 20:51:35.637: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 15
01-01 20:51:35.666: I/System.out(690): addOverlay is called
01-01 20:51:35.666: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 0
01-01 20:51:35.686: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 1
01-01 20:51:35.696: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 2
01-01 20:51:35.716: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 3
01-01 20:51:35.726: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 4
01-01 20:51:35.736: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 5
01-01 20:51:35.746: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 6
01-01 20:51:35.756: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 7
01-01 20:51:35.776: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 8
01-01 20:51:35.806: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 9
01-01 20:51:35.816: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 10
01-01 20:51:35.826: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 11
01-01 20:51:35.836: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 12
01-01 20:51:35.846: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 13
01-01 20:51:35.876: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 14
01-01 20:51:35.886: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 15
01-01 20:51:35.896: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 16
01-01 20:51:35.916: I/System.out(690): addOverlay is called
01-01 20:51:35.916: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 0
01-01 20:51:35.928: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 1
01-01 20:51:35.936: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 2
01-01 20:51:35.946: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 3
01-01 20:51:35.966: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 4
01-01 20:51:35.976: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 5
01-01 20:51:35.986: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 6
01-01 20:51:35.998: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 7
01-01 20:51:36.016: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 8
01-01 20:51:36.026: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 9
01-01 20:51:36.036: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 10
01-01 20:51:36.056: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 11
01-01 20:51:36.077: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 12
01-01 20:51:36.086: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 13
01-01 20:51:36.096: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 14
01-01 20:51:36.106: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 15
01-01 20:51:36.126: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 16
01-01 20:51:36.138: I/System.out(690): ItemizedOverlayForNearbyLocation createItem() 17
```

I dont understand why it is calling multiple times where each of them should be only created single time.As this means that i am occupying more memory for single item.

Anyone have any idea or better understanding regarding ItemizedOvelray class.please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way `populateItems` work. You would be better using [Polaris](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/Polaris), it's much simpler to use and more powerful.